# DB malformed after downloading it from S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, node-sqlite3

I have a .db file stored in an S3 bucket. I am trying to download it to a project so I can use it for a SQLite DB. THe problem is that when I download it and use it I get the next error:

```
SQLITE_CORRUPT: database disk image is malformed
```

When I try to download it using AWS GUI I can use it perfectly to build the database.
Here is the code I am using:

```
export async function downloadDB(cb: Function){
    logger.info("Beggining downloading")
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {Bucket: 'test-bucket', Key: 'data.db'};
    s3.getObject(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
        fs.writeFile("./tmp/db/data.db", data.Body.toString(), (err: any) => {
            if(err) throw new Error(err);
            else {
                logger.info(`Downloaded DB`);
                cb();
            }
        });
    })
}

export function connectToDB(){
    try{
        downloadDB(() => {
            logger.info("Beggining connection to DB");
            connection = new sqlite3.Database(path.resolve(__dirname,'../../tmp/db/data.db'), sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);
            logger.info("Connection successful")
            return connection;
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        logger.error(`${e}`);
        throw e;
    }
}
```